# How to obtain dynamic values in URL?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

My current site_url is

`www.xyz.com/folder-name/filename.php`

and now I want url as:

`www.xyz.com/dynamic-value-1/dynamic-value-2/listen`(which is static)/?

Thanks!

Comment: ok, so the question is?

Comment: Use PHP Frameworks like Laravel for easy and quick routing approach :)

Comment: You could look into some stand alone routing library. No need to learn and use a full framework just to sort out some url's.

Comment: Btw, in what way does this question have to do with PHPMyAdmin (which is a web based management software for managing MySQL databases)?

Comment: Actually the dynamic value I am talking about is value which I am retrieving from database

Comment: Which you would do with PDO functions in your script, not by running phpMyAdmin which is an *application* built with PHP.

Comment: And you tried ?

Comment: It might be a good time to read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve], then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this
Use get/post methods
`www.xyz.com/folder-name/filename.php?dynamicKey=dynamicValue`
Or use htaccess.
www.xyz.com/folder-name/filename.php/dynamicValue

My suggestion
Use framework (MVC framework recommended)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I need a dynamic value in url instead of folder name. On the basis of url, I want to show the page related to dynamic value like www.xyz.com/name/age/listen/. On the basis of name and age i want to display their details by fetching from database. If no user exists, then invalid URL.